# Guide me on iOS Developer Program

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0

I have iOS Developer Program membership for which i paid $99.  I have installed that certificate in one system, and I'm able to run my application on my real device.

Is it possible to install this certificate on my another system, such that I can run my application on another real device? When I try to install the same certificate on another system, I'm not able to get it working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read [Submitting iPhone Apps To The Apple App Store – A Step by Step Guide](http://blancer.com/tutorials/i-phone/90196/submitting-iphone-apps-to-the-apple-app-store-%E2%80%93-a-step-by-step-guide/)—in particular, the last paragraph, "Managing Your Digital Identities":

[image]

Also read: [iOS Development Workflow Guide: Managing Devices and Digital Identities](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/ios_development_workflow/128-Managing_Devices_and_Digital_Identities/devices_and_identities.html)

Answer (score 2):

You can definitely install the certificate on other systems. Please tell us the error message(s) you are getting.

Please make sure that you are [exporting your certificates correctly](http://www.nanaimostudio.com/blog/2010/7/27/problem-exporting-your-push-certificate-into-p12.html) and importing them on other system with the correct password.

Hope this helps,

Thanks,

Madhup

Answer (score 1):

You have two ways to install the App in to device.

One is: you can add the new device UDID to the provisioning profile and you can run through your system

If you want to run from other system then follow the 2nd one

2nd is: You have to create a .p12 certificate from you systems keychain.

Goto -> Application -> Utilities -> KeyChains.

right click on your certificate and click export, enter some password(for security reasons). Then it will create a .p12 certificate.

You have to install this certificate in the other system by giving the specific password that you have give while creating. Then those will be installed in the other system.

Thats it. Then follow the first step, and enjoy by installing app into other device.

Regards,
Satya